# I want to show the Progress Dialog until the data is received from the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a login activity, when the user enters the correct credentials I want to toast Welcome *Username*, but I am getting a null pointer and the app crashes.

Here's the code for your reference:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).isEmailVerified()) {


                final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                /* This method stores the logged in user data in Prevalent.currentOnlineUser, currentOnlineUser is a reference to User class*/
                saveUserPersonalData(uid);
                loadingBar.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome "+Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
             } else {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please verify your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        } else {
             loadingBar.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here at the Toast message I get a null pointer exception. I want to wait until the Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName() is not null anymore, and then show the Toast.
How can I do it, I've tried using solutions available on stack overflow but none of them has worked.

Here's the code for saveUserPersonalData() method.

```
private static void saveUserPersonalData(final String uid) {
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds) {
            if (ds.hasChild(uid)){
                Users usersData = ds.child(uid).child("personaldetails").getValue(Users.class);
                Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code inside the saveUserPersonalData()

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome "+Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

inside onDataChange